# For loop in batch file not moving file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am looping through a particular directory and if a zip file or files exist they are moved to a secondary folder in that directory however the code below doesn't seem to work i.e. it doesn't move the file. What am I doing wrong?

`for %%i in (D:\test\*.*) do if %%~xi == ".zip" move /Y "D:\test\%%~ni%%~xi" "D:\test\complete"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing the file extensions, put the current file's extension in quotation marks as well, like so:

```
for %%i in (D:\test\*.*) do if "%%~xi" == ".zip" move /Y "D:\test\%%~ni%%~xi" "D:\test\complete"
```

I tested it, and it works fine.

To use a subroutine, try this:

```
for %%i in (D:\test\*.*) do call :checkextension %%i

:checkextension
if "%~x1" == ".zip" move /Y "%~1" "D:\test\complete"
goto:eof
```

Note how each file's path (`%%i`) is passed as a parameter to the `:checkextension` subroutine, which then accesses it as `%~1` (or `%~x1` when only the extension is needed).

Comment: That worked. Thanks a bundle. Are the quotation marks required? Secondly I am attempting to create a subroutine as follows `for %%i in (D:\test\*.*) call :checkextension

:checkextension
if "%%~xi" == ".zip" move /Y "D:\test\%%~ni%%~xi" "D:\test\complete"` however it doesn't work.

Comment: You'll have to pass the filename as a parameter to the subroutine, as it cannot access the `FOR` command's parameters. I'll add a working example to my answer.